# Show that $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}= \frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, summation

Show that:
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}= \frac{\pi}{4}$$
My idea: I thought that this could be rewritten as an integral, then use trig substitution (perhaps tangent) and then solve to get the answer, but I keep getting stuck. I think I am not setting the problem up correctly. Help would be appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: You should be able to recast this as a Riemann sum..

Comment: Duly noted; I thought this looked mighty familiar.